# What is graph ($\emptyset,\emptyset$)?

Tags: graph-theory

In certain sense, empty graph is defined as a graph with no edges. So, an empty graph may contain any number of vertices. Further, if a graph with V set of vertices and E set of edges is denoted by (V, E) , then ($\emptyset, \emptyset$) corresponds to an empty graph. Now my question is what  ($\emptyset, \emptyset$) actually mean? Does it mean a graph with no edges and no vertices which doesn't sound to have any sense. So, can we use  ($\infty, \emptyset$) to represent an empty graph with no edges but may or may not contain any number of vertices?
Since i am new to this group, my question may not be appropriate to the group. If so, guide me and clarify my question please.

Comment: Some authors require that $V$ not be empty.

Comment: Yes, that's [the null graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_graph).

Comment: A graph with no edges can have any number of vertices.  I don't think many people call this an empty graph.  I have seen the term "empty graph" used to denote a graph with no vertices, and of course, no edges.

Comment: Why doesn't "a graph with no edges and no vertices" make any sense? That's definitely what the graph $(\varnothing, \varnothing)$ would be, but if you explain what bothers you about defining this graph, then an answer could properly address that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your concerns

Comment: But, sir, if a graph with no vertices is called empty graph then what is null graph? What is the point of difference between this two technologies ?

Comment: Sorry terminology not technologies.

Comment: I think "null" refers to there being no *edges*, without reference to how many vertices. [I also don't know if no vertices, no edges counts as a "graph"-- that would depend on definition of a graph.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In graph theory, terminology often differs among different graph theorists so you may even see different definitions in different books (I see this while I was trying to learn the terminology "path", "trail", "cycle",etc.). So you can go with whichever is easier for you to understand and if you are a student in highschool or university, I suggest you to go with the definitions that your teacher gives.

In this case as I see, since **empty graph** is used for the graphs that have no edges and **null graph** can be used for a particular case where number of vertices is zero (source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EmptyGraph.html), in order to prevent confusion I would suggest you to distinguish them as

- **Empty Graph:** A graph with no edges generally (So $(\infty, \emptyset)$ is here).
- **Null Graph:** A graph with no edges and no vertices (So $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$ is here).

But as I said earlier, this can vary from book to book or person to person so if you see a different definition, you may try to adapt it or while solving a problem, you can specify what are the definitions you are using. If you are a self-learner, this doesn't hurt you in my opinion. Otherwise if you are a student who is taking a course including graph theory, I suggest you to follow the definitions that your teacher gives for now, and then you can accept whatever definition you want as long as that definition exists.

Comment: Up until now I had empty and null graph switched. There are sources that do that as well. Better to speak of an edgeless graph then, I guess.